# How to click on a parent whose child contains a particular text

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am new to webdriver and I am automating a site. In which I have to find a text on that page and I want to click on its parent div. Can anyone please help?
Below is the HTML code.

```html
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6">
<p>
<strong class="detailShow ng-binding" ng-click="showJobs('NonInvite',item.taskId)"> TEST CR1 START DATE </strong>
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Share what have you tried already

Comment: // below mention the task name  
     Thread.sleep(1000);
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6' and .//p/strong[contains(text(),'TEST CR1 START DATE')]]")).click();
 
I am not sure whether it is correct.

Comment: @MansiShrimali Can you consider updating your Usecase why you need to click on the `parent div`? Consider showcasing your work & the error you are facing. Thanks

Comment: @ DebanjanB Actually I have numbers of records on a page and each of them has a title. And if I click on a title it would open an modal. and if I click on its parent then it will open another modal which is the required one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve this is directly using xpath.

You can choose the 'more ugly' way like this:

```
.//strong[contains(@class,'detailShow')]/../..
```

Explanation:

`/..`   - this is how you get the parent element. Having just one, means that you'll get the `<p>` tag, so to get the `<div>` you need another one.

Or, you can go in a better manner like this:

```
.//strong[contains(@class,'detailShow')]/ancestor::div[@class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6']
```

Explanation:
`ancestor::div` - this one goes up until and returns all parent that are `<div>` tags. Since you need only the first `<div>` parent, you need to specify which one, therefore: `ancestor::div[@class='col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-6']`

Now, if the bootstrap class is your only identifier, and there is a chance you may be inside a `<table>` you can also go with `ancestor::div[1]`

Comment: It didn't work but gave me the idea what I need to do. Thank you very much.

Comment: Well, then use the p tag as well between the  strong tag and ancestor. And for the ancestor you can use the second case with ancestor::div[1]. Anyway, without a more complete html code it's hard to guess what's the best way of approaching this.